# Why accent is cut with this regular expression

Tags: php, regex

While I was working, I found the following regular expression:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('/(^|[^a-z0-9-])()($|[^a-z0-9-])/mi', '$1x$2$3', 'anulación', -1, $count);
```

And the result is:

'anulaci�x�n'

I have no clue why is happening, the caracter is uncodified.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try with the `u` modifier `/(^|[^a-z0-9-])()($|[^a-z0-9-])/miu`

Comment: The `/u` modifier is necessary when you want `preg_replace` to work with Unicode strings. Even if your pattern has no `\p{L}` or similar constructs.

Comment: It works! Thanks very much.